# Let's get critical: Sep 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Sustainable Living Stack Exchange](http://sustainability.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: **Many thanks to everyone who took part in the evaluation.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Does repeatedly turning on and off an appliance tend to damage it?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/2972/does-repeatedly-turning-on-and-off-an-appliance-tend-to-damage-it)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How to conserve water while bathing?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/2984/how-to-conserve-water-while-bathing)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Does vegetarianism help in protecting nature?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/2955/does-vegetarianism-help-in-protecting-nature)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [What causes photovoltaic (solar) cells to degrade?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/2943/what-causes-photovoltaic-solar-cells-to-degrade)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Is the energy used to manufacture and install solar panels in proper balance with the energy output from them?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/2968/is-the-energy-used-to-manufacture-and-install-solar-panels-in-proper-balance-wit)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [How can I use my own body as an energy source for greater environmental sustainability?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/2951/how-can-i-use-my-own-body-as-an-energy-source-for-greater-environmental-sustaina)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Indoor composting with limited space](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/2973/indoor-composting-with-limited-space)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Do #4 (♶ LDPE) plastic bags need to be recycled at grocery stores like #2 (♴ HDPE) plastic bags?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/2959/do-4-%e2%99%b6-ldpe-plastic-bags-need-to-be-recycled-at-grocery-stores-like-2-%e2%99%b4-hdp)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Is there a green alternative for spray polyurethane foam?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/2946/is-there-a-green-alternative-for-spray-polyurethane-foam)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [What is a sustainable solution to cats in the tropics?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/2980/what-is-a-sustainable-solution-to-cats-in-the-tropics)

**Net Score: -5** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

Answer (score 4):

Well, that didn't go well when I did it. I don't think any of the searches I did, for each question, had any results from this site in the first two pages of results (20 in total). I think this is partly a result of the Panda 4.0 google update, which downgraded this site quite a lot. Panda 4.1 seems to have given a bit of recovery, but it seems like we need quite a bit more, and better, content, with inbound links, to recover our google ranking.

Comment: It may depend on your search terms. Some questions I had trouble finding, others weren't a problem.